# opencart clear:both generates a gap

Tags: css, css-float, opencart

http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42

[image]

If you use firebug, or chrome's inspect element and insert this code

```
<div style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;"></div>
<div style="background:green;width:100px;height:100px;float:right;"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

in .product-info .right you get a white space around 400px of height.Same happens if I try to modify my template.

It works fine if I create a html document and paste the same code

```
<html>
test<br />

<div style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="background:green;width:100px;height:100px;float:right;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    test again
</html>
```

The problem is clearly somewhere in opencart, I can't find where though.

edit:If i put display:none; on column left it doesn't create a gap, so there is something wrong with column left.

edit:I found the solution myself.I fixed the floats by floating right column

```
.product-info .right {
float:right;
width:470px;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure should be like this

```
<div class="right">

<div style="overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;"></div>
  <div style="background:green;width:100px;height:100px;float:right;"></div>
</div>


  <div style="" class="description"> <!-- remove the style clear:both -->
    <span>Brand:</span> <a href="http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/product&amp;manufacturer_id=8">Apple</a><br>
    <span>Product Code:</span> Product 15<br>
    <span>Reward Points:</span> 100<br>
    <span>Availability:</span> In Stock
  </div>

......
your remaining divs goes here
.....

</div>
```

---

Screen shot:

[image]